# what will be the correct code to ssh into another region?

Tags: ssh, terraform, ssh-keys

Is there any corrections I need to make to this terraform code for my security group rule to recognize my security group?

```
# security group public
resource "aws_security_group" "public_sg" {
  name        = "security-public"
  description = "security group for public"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.us_west_2_vpc.id

  ingress {
    description = "ssh"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }


  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "tf_sg"
  }
}


# security group private
resource "aws_security_group" "private_sg" {
  name        = "security-private"
  description = "security group for private"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.us_west_2_vpc.id

  ingress {
    description     = "ssh"
    from_port       = 22
    to_port         = 22
    protocol        = "tcp"
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.public_sg.id]
  }
}


resource "aws_security_group" "allow_ssh" {
  name        = "allow-ssh"
  description = "allow ssh access"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.us_west_2_vpc.id

  # allow SSH trafic from us-east-1 instances
  ingress {
    description = "ssh"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["10.1.0.0/16"]
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "allow_ssh_from_east" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.allow_ssh.id

  type                     = "ingress"
  from_port                = 22
  to_port                  = 22
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  source_security_group_id = aws_security_group.allow_ssh_east.id
}


# security group public
resource "aws_security_group" "public_sg_east" {
  name        = "security-public"
  description = "security group for public"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.us_east_1_vpc.id
  provider    = aws.east

  ingress {
    description = "ssh"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }


  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "tf_sg"
  }
}


# security group private
resource "aws_security_group" "private_sg1" {
  name        = "security-private"
  description = "security group for private"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.us_east_1_vpc.id
  provider    = aws.east

  ingress {
    description     = "ssh"
    from_port       = 22
    to_port         = 22
    protocol        = "tcp"
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.public_sg_east.id]
  }
}


 resource "aws_security_group" "allow_ssh_east" {
  name        = "allow-ssh-east"
  description = "allow ssh access east"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.us_east_1_vpc.id
  provider    = aws.east

  # allow SSH trafic from us-west-2 instances
 ingress {
    description = "ssh"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "allow_ssh_from_west" {
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.allow_ssh_east.id
  provider                 = aws.east
  type                     = "ingress"
  from_port                = 22
  to_port                  = 22
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  source_security_group_id = aws_security_group.allow_ssh.id
}
```

I can find the security group on my console but the sgr is not recognizing it with this error:

authorizing Security Group (sg-02c68716a41db49c3) Rule (sgrule-927988265): InvalidGroup.NotFound: The security group 'sg-04f7517f268e93249' does not exist

I tried what I can but nothing is working.
I'm trying to ssh from one region to another.